# GLTF Loader not working and doesn't load 3D model

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, gltf

I'm trying to upload a 3D model to my scene in three.js however I have trouble doing this.
I decided to recreate an example to practice which is shown below but I still get error and it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Website first attempt</title>

        <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
        <script type = "module"src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script type = "module" src="js/GLTFLoader.js"></script>


        <style>
            body { margin: 0;}
            canvas { display: block; }
        </style>

    </head>


    <body>
        <div class = "wave"></div>
        <script type = "module">


            var scene, camera, renderer, controls;
            var hlight,directionalLight, light, light2, light3, light4;


            function init () {
                //scene
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xdddddd );


                //camera
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,1,5000);
                camera.rotation.y = 45/180*Math.PI;
                camera.position.x = 800;
                camera.position.y = 100;
                camera.position.z = 1000;


                //render                
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

                document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                //controls
                controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

                hlight = new THREE.AmbientLight (0x404040,100);
                scene.add(hlight);

                directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff,100);
                directionalLight.position.set(0,1,0);
                directionalLight.castShadow = true;
                scene.add(directionalLight);

                light = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
                light.position.set(0,300,500);
                scene.add(light);

                light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
                light2.position.set(500,100,0);
                scene.add(light2);

                light3 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
                light3.position.set(0,100,-500);
                scene.add(light3);

                light4 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
                light4.position.set(-500,300,500);
                scene.add(light4);

                var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
                loader.load('scene.gltf', function(gltf){
                car = gltf.scene.children[0];
                car.scale.set(0.5,0.5,0.5);
                scene.add(gltf.scene);
                animate();
        });









            }




            function onWindowResize () {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                }

                window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

            function animate () {

                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                controls.update();               
                render();

            }

            function render() {

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

            init ();
            animate();


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comes with an error:

> GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/build/three.module.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
>   (Not Found) index4.html:78 Uncaught TypeError: THREE.GLTFLoader is not
>   a constructor
>       at init (index4.html:78)
>       at index4.html:122

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think easier to stick to the example's code style and organize your imports like so:

```
<script type = "module">

    import * as THREE from '../build/three.module.js';

    import { OrbitControls } from './jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
    import { GLTFLoader } from './jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

    var scene, camera, renderer, controls;
```

Meaning `three.module.js`, `OrbitControls` and `GLTFLoader` are ES6 modules. In this case, you can create an instance of `GLTFLoader` without the `THREE` namespace. Same for `OrbitControls`.

Notice that it's no good approach to mix ES6 modules with non-ES6 modules. If you do so, you will be inevitably faced with issues which are really hard to track down. E.g. libraries like `three.js` get included twice.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I have tried using the import statement before. However, it doesn't know how to locate it even though I link it to my local JS files like this. `import { OrbitControls } from './js/OrbitControls.js';` maybe i'm linking it wrong?. This is why I stuck to the original method of linking scripts.

Comment: Well, you can use the Chrome dev tools (Network Tab) to verify if your files are actually loaded. If that's the case, you have to be aware that modules like `OrbitControls` and `GLTFLoader` load dependent files from a specific path. If they can't find `three.module.js` under this location, the usage won't work. Alternatively, consider to use the `npm` package of `three.js` and use a simple build to manage your application like in this example repository: https://github.com/Mugen87/three-jsm